# Difference Between SRAM SX eagle chain and SRAM NX eagle chain(12 speed)?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, chain, drivetrain, mechanical

I have a Trek X-Caliber 8 with a SRAM SX Eagle 12 speed drive train, but I only have a SRAM NX Eagle chain. What is the exact difference between the two chains, and how can I modify my chain to make it work with my bike?

- I do not have another Eagle chain
- The chain is too long, not too short
- I do have a chain breaker, but the pins seem to be stamped so you can't take them out? My chain breaker might just not be up to the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NX chain is of slightly higher quality, so it will last longer and shift better. That's not relevant here though.

Yes, you need to shorten a new chain in most cases. The riveted pins increase the chain's strength, but do require a decent chain tool to punch out. Hold the new chain up beside the old chain, matching link to link, and break it at the same length/link count.